# Google spreadsheets sheet.getCharts() only works when spreadsheet is opened?

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm can not get the chart of my Sheet when the spreadsheet is closed. My goal is to update and send the chart as email and I have managed that easily when Google Spreadsheet is open.
But when CLOSED, the length of charts is "0".

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var charts = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet").getCharts();
```

So, are there any restrictions when using this command or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getActiveSpreadsheet` only works if there's an active spreadsheet. (i.e.: When there's a spreadsheet open.)

You should open the spreadsheet via one of the open methods detailed in the [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) (specifically `open`, `openById` or `openByUrl`) and then set it as active first.

For example:

```
var testSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1234567890");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(testSpreadsheet);
```

Comment: `setActiveSpreadsheet(ssName)` is not mandatory, you can get the sheet from the spreadsheet object without making it active (using `getSheetByName` or `getSheets[n]`). `setActiveSpreadsheet` is only useful to update the User interface in the browser.